# How to add meta data to every cell in all tables of a relational database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, metadata, relational-database

I have a relational database (I am using SQL Server 2008) with scores of tables. I need to capture a lot of meta data for each cell (not just the row) in every table. Thankfully, the metadata schema is expected to be consistent across all tables.

Further, the metadata should be queryable as well. I did not some across any such direct support built in.

What is the best possible approach?

Comment: Sorry Yahia to revert after a long time. I need to be able to store some status value for each data element I create. I can create a separate table for it but want to avoid for performance and query purpose. One example of this need is that if the data is blank, I need to know why. So I am supposed to store the reason along with, such as 'Not Available' | 'Not Applicable' | 'Requested For', etc.

Comment: are you aiming for some sort of "auditing" (i.e. some sort of protocol about every change made with timestamp and who made it...) ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using SQL Server's [extended properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx).