# SQL Server CELL METADATA

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, metadata

What I want to do seems simple - for each cell in a table of my SQL Server database (2008R2 or above), I want to associate an integer (which is a reference to another table). I have searched the internets high and low, which worries me a bit, because there is no mention of such a thing.

Closest I found was this StackOverflow question: [How to add meta data to every cell in all tables of a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543896/how-to-add-meta-data-to-every-cell-in-all-tables-of-a-relational-database) - which didn't seem to get an answer either way.

If it is not possible, what would be the best way to go? My current thoughts are an `XML` column with the column value, the column datatype and integer for linking. But it seems clumsy to me. Any bright sparks got a better idea?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, normally it is done not through some "meta data", but by simple extra columns. Add as many columns as you need to the table and store your integers in them.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, that is an option but I am hoping not to have to add the extra columns - but if that is the accepted way of doing what I have to do, then that's what I'll do!

Comment: Have you looked at sys.columns? I've worked with metadata heavily in the past but am at a loss as to what you'd use it for here? Can you elaborate how the linking of cells would work?

Comment: Certainly!  The link from the cell (or atomic piece of data) to the table would contain info on when,why, and how etc that particular cell was changed - a bit of an audit trail.  That information would then be used independent of the primary data.  I am looking at Vladimir's solution above as an acceptable alternative to my idea, since it seems it can't be done.

Comment: @James I think that would be a better approach for sure.